# Is it possible write the data in widget to the main app Coredata without group?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I found a lot of solution online, and many of them need to add the project into a group. But i do not own a developer account, i just a student, and i just want to make a widget and the user can interactive by using the button, and add to coredata in the main app, so is it any solution can help me? thanks

Comment: you must have to enroll developer program to use group

Comment: i know, but is there any solution that i can write the data to main app coredata in widget without using group? thanks

Comment: i think you can able to access core data file using NSFileManage

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. Extensions on iOS are separate processes from their apps. Sandboxing means that they can't access each other's data unless they use an app group. It's not just Core Data that has this rule, it's any kind of file access. If you won't set up an app group, you might try using a web service to store the data online. Both the app and the extension could use the same web service to share data.